# sbt multiple degree dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I am following the code in this blog: https://pbassiner.github.io/blog/defining_multi-project_builds_with_sbt.html. It shows me how to create a multi project build with dependencies. multi1 depends on common, and multi2 depends on common as well. But what if I have a 2 degree dependency? ie. multi1 depends on common and multi2 depends on multi1?

FROM THIS: common -> mutli1; common -> multi2
TO THIS:   common -> multi1 -> multi2

Precisely, how does such a dependency tree change this code? (Copied from the blog)

```
lazy val global = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(settings)
  .aggregate(
    common,
    multi1,
    multi2
  )

lazy val common = project
  .settings(
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )

lazy val multi1 = project
  .settings(
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies ++ Seq(
      dependencies.monocleCore,
      dependencies.monocleMacro
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(
    common
  )

lazy val multi2 = project
  .settings(
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies ++ Seq(
      dependencies.pureconfig
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(
    common
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

> common -> mutli1; common -> multi2

means `milti1.dependsOn(common)` and `milti2.dependsOn(common)`.

> common -> multi1 -> multi2

means `milti2.dependsOn(multi1)` and `milti1.dependsOn(common)`.

So you just need to change one line saying that `multi2` depends on `multi1` (instead of `common`):

```
lazy val multi2 = project
  .settings(
    ...
  )
  .dependsOn(
    multi1
  )
```

Transitive dependencies work as expected.